# Product Title being blocked

Tags: css, woocommerce

The product title that used to be over price and swatches is not showing up. I've removed ever plugin, and deleted all the extra css, and to no avail the product title doesn't show up. [Here you can find a link to a single product page from my website as an example](https://www.dontcursekids.com/product/the-ckoos-og-tee-bw-2/)  Any suggestions on how to bring it back would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking the CSS it seems this line is the cause, it is in Line 57 of your CSS

```
.entry-title {
    display: none;
}
```

This is how it looks on the inspector.

[image]

and this is how it looks after I remove it. 
Remove it on your CSS and I think it will solve it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems the problem is in the css class defined:

> `<h1 class="entry-title">The ckoos OG Tee B&W</h1>`
>   `.entry-title { display: none; }`

*found on line 617 on the index*

just change the display back to `block` or `inline-block.`

Comment: Thank you. I found it on line 57. but I used the inline block to bring back the product title which is the right side. very helpful thank you